# Prove $\forall p\in(0,1), \theta\in [0,\pi /2];\cos^p(\theta)≤\cos(p\theta)$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Take $\log(\cos^p(θ))≤\log(\cos(pθ))$ and use derivative, I can find a proof here.

I am wondering this can be solved without using derivative.

Comment: It helped but I want to know if there is a solution without using derivative or not

Comment: @jaybo On the possible duplicate page, the proof on Sep 3 '14 at 8:07 by [Kim Jong Un](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/136641/kim-jong-un) doesn't, as far as I can tell, use derivatives. Instead, it just uses that cosine is concave in that region & [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Comment: @JohnOmielan \cos(p\theta)=\cos(p\theta+(1-p)0)\geq p\cos(\theta)+(1-p)\cos(0)=p\cos(\theta)+(1-p). Does concavity used here? I couldn't find why this inequality holds. I don't know how I can transform this code into math symbols.

Comment: Yes, concavity is used there, with it being why the stated inequality holds. For more info, please read Wikipedia's [Concave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function).

Comment: I didn't learn formal definition of concavity so I didn't understand. Now I can understand. Thank you.